# Eeeek! The LHC has imploded the universe!

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, flag-queue

If I use a mod-binding vote (from the context of the queue) on a post in the flag queue that has 1 close vote, I get this error:

[image: enter link description here]

Eeeeek!

Comment: We always knew the LHC would implode the universe...

Comment: @J.Steen Actually...that makes for a much better bug report title :P

Comment: No it doesn't, and you know it. Funnier, and definitely satisfyingly inappropriate, perhaps. ;)

Comment: More likely to get you Featured Question or whatever the badge is called...

Comment: I feel [this image/meme](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/000/374/AccidentallyUniverse.jpg) fits...

Comment: I like this question better.

Comment: Should this be tagged [catastrophe]? Sounds serious.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did you just *really* edit out an E in the Eeeek to make it follow the standard length of Eeeeks?

Comment: @J.Steen: We have standards, you know.  Because standards.

Comment: @J.Steen There's no "standard length", but the eeeekiness is reflected in the number of e's.

Comment: @Manishearth So it's a little bit less eeeeky than you initially thought?